# image Orientation CSS property doesn't support in angular application

Tags: html, angular, css, angular6, angular5

1. Image orientation CSS property doesn't support in chrome browser by using angular
2. When I upload an image it's showing the anti-clockwise direction

Comment: please provide a [mcve] of your issue.

Comment: After uploading an image, it's showing reverse direction

Comment: I have used Image Orientation CSS property but it's working in chrome browser

Comment: I am using angular material

Comment: I am using below code:

Comment: .img{image-orientation: from-image;}

Comment: **Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve] of your issue** (in a snippet or in an online sandbox) **. If you don't, your question will be deleted.** And do not post code in the comments, you have a rich text editor in your question.

Comment: I have to get the EXIF data for the image and then write a process to transform the image to the orientation

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have to get the EXIF data for the image and then write a process to transform the image to the orientation that you want.